# Query regarding merging values of a Map to the first key of the Map

Tags: java-8

I've a hashmap with few key value pairs.

My requirement is to iterate over the all the key and value pairs but merge all the value to the first key of the hashset.

For example,

```
Map<String,Integer> resultMap = new HashMap();
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap();
map.put("abc",1);
map.put("def",2);
map.put("efg",3);
map.put("uvw",4);
map.put("xyz",5);
```

I want to do something similar to this:

```
map.foreach((k,v)->resultMap.merge(k,v,(v1,v2)->v1+v2)
```

**the resultant map will have only one key i.e. "abc" and value as (1+2+3+4+5)=15**

How can I do this efficiently using java8?

Comment: hope you are aware that there is no deterministic *first* key of a HashSet. So you might just as well sum all the values against a key you might already be aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
String firstKey = "";
for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry:map.entrySet()) {
     if (resultMap.isEmpty()) firstKey = entry.getKey();
     resultMap.merge(firstKey, entry.getValue(), Integer::sum);
}
```

stream version:

```
resultMap = map.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(HashMap::new, (m, e) ->
                    {
                      if (m.isEmpty()) m.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
                      else m.merge(m.entrySet().stream()
                       .findFirst().get().getKey(),e.getValue(),Integer::sum);
                    }
                    , HashMap::putAll);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sum all the values of the map first and then add it resultMap with first key.

```
int sum = map.values().stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);

Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry = map.entrySet().iterator().next();

String key = entry.getKey();
resultMap.put(key,sum);
```

Using Merge function, first sum all the values with "randomKey" not present in the original Map. Then replace random key with original map's first key

```
map.forEach((k,v)->resultMap.merge("randomKey",v,Integer::sum));
        
Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry = map.entrySet().iterator().next();

Object obj = resultMap.remove("randomKey");

resultMap.put(entry.getKey(), (Integer) obj);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I’ve to make use of the map merge function

Comment: Wondering why have to use merge function? Have updated the answer using merge function. Please check